# I'm not able to access all vf pages

Tags: apex, visualforce, admin

I'm not able to access all my VF pages like shown in bellow picture. Can anyone tell me what settings need to change?[image]

Comment: Click on Edit link and see what criteria you have specified for the view.

Comment: It is showing only one list view, Might be All VF Pages list view is overridden with some conditions which is displaying only one result for that condition.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes when you create a new view the All view gets lost.

Simply "create new view" named all, with no filters and save.

Should be good to go then